# Getting element from DOM with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

EDIT: 
[JSFIDDLE here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/TheRealPapa/v0Lnzw5v/). I am trying to mirror DESKTOP 1 to MOBILE 1 elements (same for #2) in the fiddle. The error is shown in console.

Got to DESKTOP 1 and select NEW RATE from the list. Have the console opened to see the issue. Thanks!

---

I get an element from my layout with this command:

```
var eqTaxSelect = $('table#mob-tab-' + num).find('select.tax_rate').get();
```

I then try to toggle it:

```
toggleField($(eqTaxSelect), $(eqTaxSelect).nextElementSibling); <-- FAILS

function toggleField(hideObj, showObj) {
    hideObj.style.display = 'none';     <-- FAILS HERE
    showObj.style.display = 'inline';
    showObj.focus();
}
```

with:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'nextElementSibling' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong when assigning the element to my variable? This function works for `this` inside click event listeners for example.
Thanks!

The HTML I am toggling came from this forum, essentially a select with a hidden input so new entries can be added as well as using an entry from the options list.

Comment: It'd be easier to understand if you provided a [mcve].

Comment: sorry, maybe this is easier @zer00ne

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong when assigning the element to my variable?

You are passing `jQuery()` objects, where `toggleField` expects `DOM` elements. `jQuery()` does not have a `.nextElementSibling` method. Remove calls to [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery) at

```
toggleField($(eqTaxSelect), $(eqTaxSelect).nextElementSibling);
```

replace with

```
toggleField(eqTaxSelect, eqTaxSelect.nextElementSibling);
```

to pass `DOM` elements to `toggleField`.

Comment: @TheRealPapa What is the `.nextElementSibling` of `eqTaxSelect` element? Can you include `html` at Question? Create stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: @TheRealPapa Try passing `num` to `.get()`, e.g., `var eqTaxSelect = $('table#mob-tab-' + num).find('select.tax_rate').get(num);`

Answer (score 0):

test with

`console.log(eqTaxSelect)`

see on inspector (CTRL+SHIF+I CHROME). if this is ok,

just do this

`toggleField(eqTaxSelect, eqTaxSelect.nextElementSibling)`

withouth "$"

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your statement

```
toggleField(eqTaxSelect, eqTaxSelect.nextElementSibling);
```

fails is because of the way you are populating the eqTaxSelect

```
var eqTaxSelect = $('table#mob-tab-' + num).find('select.tax_rate').get();
```

It should be modified as

```
var eqTaxSelect = $('table#mob-tab-' + num).find('select.tax_rate').get(0);
```

reason being, get() without an index returns an array and the way you are operating, you are expecting an single dom element.

[jQuery documentation for get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: Hi @Sreekanth, awesome, this is close now. The error has moved to the `nextSibiling` statement in the toggle. See the fiddle

Comment: You are looking at the wrong selector for eqTaxSelect. It should be $('tr#mob-tab-' + num) instead of $('table#mob-tab-' + num).

Comment: Hi sorry it did not. I ended up solving it by targeting the elements via `data` attributes. Thanks